# Which .NET dependency injection framework do you use?

Tags: .net, frameworks, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

Currently there are quite a few DI/IoC-frameworks for .NET out there (http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ListOfNETDependencyInjectionContainersIOC.aspx).
I find it quite hard to choose. Therefore I wanted to measure the public opinion and see which framework is the most popular - so please post your favorite framework here and let the people vote...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm currently using [Castle.Windsor](http://www.castleproject.org/container/index.html). Mainly because of the integration it has with the Rhino Tools library.

Answer (score 1):

I've been watching Kzu (creator of Moq)'s [screencast series](http://www.clariusconsulting.net/blogs/kzu/archive/2009/02/02/116399.aspx) as he develops [Funq](http://funq.me) - a DI framework that makes extensive use of lambdas the same way Moq does. No release yet but I'm looking forward to trying it out.

Answer (score 1):

StructureMap

I love the fact that I can configure it all using the fluent interface (aka Configuration DSL). Typesafe configuration is a must when I do refactoring.

Answer (score 1):

[Autofac](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/). Type-safe and plays well with code-refactoring. Apart from the boiler-plate stuff, I found the delegate factories to be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Windsor](http://www.castleproject.org/container/index.html) or Unity, and decide based on a POC

Unity is not so bloated up so far, you could go with that based on your project type - especially if you are using unity dependent frameworks like CompositeWPF

See another thread on SO about the same, [Enterprise Library Unity vs Other IoC Containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/411660/enterprise-library-unity-vs-other-ioc-containers/552237)

Comment: I'd just add that Composite WPF is not dependent on unity - all unity support is provided by a UnityExtensions module which you don't have to reference. You can (and I do) use Castle or another container.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Structuremap](http://docs.structuremap.net/) which is a Dependency Injection / Inversion of Control tool for .Net

Answer (score 0):

**[Unity](http://www.codeplex.com/unity)**
It's simple and unintrusive, yet type-safe. And it is created by *Microsoft Pattern & Pratices* group.

Comment: Judging by http://unity.codeplex.com/SourceControl/PatchList.aspx, they do not accept any community contributions.

Comment: Given Microsoft does not grow or sell food, what to microsofities eat ?