# Dependency injection frameworks for .Net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Please Suggest an Easy to use DI framework for .net. I am using mvc2.

Comment: Voting to close. This is purely argumentative.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21288/which-net-dependency-injection-frameworks-are-worth-looking-into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/555943/which-net-dependency-injection-framework-do-you-use and many more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in our project also ASP.NET MVC 2 we using [Ninject](http://weblogs.asp.net/shijuvarghese/archive/2010/04/30/dependency-injection-in-nerddinner-app-using-ninject.aspx) it is really nice and has a pretty cool name :)

Comment: Thats a good reason to use any technology. :/

Answer (score 4):

Scott Hanselman has an great list on his blog. 
[List of .NET Dependency Injection Containers (IOC)](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ListOfNETDependencyInjectionContainersIOC.aspx)

Phil Haack has a blog post about using [StructureMap](http://structuremap.github.com/structuremap/Default.htm) with [TDD and Dependency Injection with ASP.NET MVC](http://haacked.com/archive/2007/12/07/tdd-and-dependency-injection-with-asp.net-mvc.aspx). It's a little old (12/2007) but still a good read on the topic.

Answer (score 2):

I like [Castle Windsor](http://stw.castleproject.org/Windsor.MainPage.ashx), and it's performant and stable. But there is a [lot of frameworks](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ListOfNETDependencyInjectionContainersIOC.aspx) out there, that does almost the same thing with small differences in features.

Comment: IoC framework should be small, packed in one assembly, do just what it needs to do, nothing more. Castle Windsor looks like overkill to me. If you need just a knife, why do one have to buy a whole toolbox?

Comment: @Lex: Windsor is Castle.Windsor.dll + Castle.Core.dll. Are you sure you mean two assemblies is *overkill*? Have you ever actually *used* Windsor?

Comment: No, it was enough to open these two libraries in Reflector to see what's there. 80% has nothing to do with IoC.