# How to decide between MEF and any IoC container?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, ioc-container, mef

In which scenario should we use which? How to decide on which one to choose? And under which circumstances would we choose to use both together?

I have previously worked with Unity Container ([unity-container](/questions/tagged/unity-container)).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MEF vs. any IoC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1288376/mef-vs-any-ioc)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Tricky question - since the two do indeed overlap to a certain degree.

I would say this:

- use any useful IoC if you're primarily concerned about dependency injection for the sake of decoupling your components, e.g. for the ability to be able to inject a mock instead (for testing)
- use MEF especially if you're more into being extensible, e.g. be able to "load all assemblies from that directory that export a certain interface", and if you need to be extensible and open for third parties (like Visual Studio: offer a public API so others can write an extension for your app). This is where MEF really shines

For MEF and Unity, there's also the [MEF and Unity Integration Layer](http://pwlodek.blogspot.com/2009/05/unity-mef-integration-layer.html) to combine the strengths of both tools together.

I would also recommend you check out Ayende's [excellent blog post](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2008/09/25/the-managed-extensibility-framework.aspx) on what differentiates MEF from an IoC.

Comment: I find Ayende's blog post confusing. For example, MEF is *not* able to "query meta data without loading assemblies" and doesn't have "contract adapters" contrary to what the post says. There is a lot of hand-waving in that post.

Answer (score 1):

MEF shines when you have 3rd parties writing plug-ins, that implement interfaces and you wish to be able to version your interface without breaking the 3rd party plug in you can’t recompile.  In exchange MEF is more complex than a raw IoC.

So I would say IoC if everything is compiled as part of the same build system, and MEF if you need to cope with add-ins you can’t recompile yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Glen Block (former Product Manager of MEF) has covered this pretty well on his blog:

- [Should I use MEF for my general IoC needs?](http://codebetter.com/blogs/glenn.block/archive/2009/08/16/should-i-use-mef-for-my-general-ioc-needs.aspx)
- [Should I use MEF with an IoC container? - Part 1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/gblock/archive/2009/11/01/should-i-use-mef-with-an-ioc-container-part-1.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I heard a great explanation of this (apologies to the author, I've forgotten who it was): At a very high level, IoC is good when you want one thing for a given interface, MEF is good for when you want all things from a given interface.

For instance in IoC you want to return a specific *single* concrete class for an interface:

```
For<ICarFactory>().Use<CarFactory>();
```

Whenever you want to use a `ICanFactory` you will get a `CarFactory`.

MEF is good for saying give me all the car factories:

```
CheapCarFactory : ICarFactory
FamilyCarFactory : ICarFactory 
LuxuryCarFactory : ICarFactory
```

Etc.

Comment: Nearly all current IOC containers do this.