# What is different between and purpose of MEF and Unity?

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, unity-container, mef

I just start study DI (I'm working on WPF/Silverlight but I have a plan to move to ASP.NET). After I read some DI articles from internet there are two Frameworks that I'm interested in, MEF and Unity. I want to know what is the real-world different between them and which one is good to go.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MEF vs. any IoC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1288376/mef-vs-any-ioc)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

The main difference is that with unity you will explicitly register each class you want to use in the composition:

```
var container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterType<IFoo,Foo>();
container.RegisterType<IBar,Bar>();
...
var program = container.Resolve<Program>();
program.Run();
```

In MEF on the other hand, you mark classes with attributes instead of registering them somewhere else:

```
[Export(typeof(IFoo))]
public Foo
{
   ...
}
```

At first sight this looks like a minor syntactic difference, but it is actually more important than that. MEF is designed to allow for the  dynamic discovery of parts. For example, with a `DirectoryCatalog` you can design your application in such a way that you can extend it by simply dropping new DLLs in the application folder.

In this example, MEF will find and instantiate all classes with an `[Export(typeof(IPlugin))]` attribute in the given directory and passes those instances to the `Program` constructor:

```
[Export]
public class Program
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<IPlugin> plugins;

    [ImportingConstructor]
    public Program(
       [ImportMany(typeof(IPlugin))] IEnumerable<IPlugin> plugins)
    {
        this.plugins = plugins;
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Entry point:

```
public static void Main()
{
    using (var catalog = new DirectoryCatalog(".","*"))
    using (var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog))
    {
        var program = container.GetExportedValue<Program>();
        program.Run();
    }
}
```

To accommodate such dynamic composition scenarios, MEF has a concept of "stable composition", which means that when it runs into a missing dependency somewhere it will simply mark the part as unavailable and will continue the composition anyway.

[Stable composition can be quite useful](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nblumhardt/archive/2009/07/17/light-up-or-mef-optional-exports.aspx), but it also makes it [very difficult to debug a failed composition](http://mindinthewater.blogspot.com/2011/05/problems-encountered-when-using-mef-as.html). So if you don't need dynamic discovery of parts and "stable composition", I would use a regular DI container instead of MEF. Unlike MEF, regular DI containers will give you clear error messages when a dependency is missing.

It might also be possible to get the best of both worlds by using a DI container which integrates with MEF, like [Autofac](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/). Use Autofac to compose the core application, and MEF for the parts which need to be dynamically extensible.

Comment: I wished it was that easy. Unfortunately its not. MEF is giving me tons of headache. It throws tons of "ImportCardinalityMismatchException" errors and it has to do with the fact that MEF is very badly design in terms of debugging capabilities it seems. Nowhere in the error code do I find a reference to where the export could not be assembled. I am about to completely dump any attempt to work with MEF.

Comment: @Freddy: It's not clear which part of my answer you are commenting on. I literally wrote that it is "very difficult to debug a failed composition" and linked to my blog post about that. Where did I say that it was easy?

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstood, you posted the Main method and said "simply dropping DLLs" and "MEF will find all classes with an Export attribute" which is unfortunately all but easy and straightforward. I have been pulling out hairs over this. Fair points re debugging though. I was more relating to the fact that MEF is not as straightforward to use as one may think looking at your code sample. Maybe I got the wrong impression reading through your answer.

Comment: This should help debugging MEF:
1. Configure the Visual Studio debugger to break when exceptions are thrown.
2. Configure your CompositionContainer object to disable rejection.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff603380%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: It should be pointed out that the differences between MEF and Unity are because the libraries serve different purposes. Unity is an IoC container and is intended to be used for DI. MEF is not an IoC container even though you can make it function as one, however poorly. MEF is intended for [Extensibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/mef/index).

Answer (score 22):

There are lots of options for doing DI. First of all you should realize that DI isn't about tools, but rather about patterns and principles. You can use DI just fine without a tool. If you do that, we call it **Poor Man's DI**.

However, that said, [there are lots of DI Containers available for .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148908/which-dependency-injection-tool-should-i-use). Unity is just one of them.

MEF looks a lot like a DI Container, but currently solves a different problem - that of extensibility. Instead of external configuration of components (which all DI Containers use) it uses an attribute-based *discovery mechanism*.

Comment: Read this guy's book!! It has set me on the path of DI righteousness :D. http://www.manning.com/seemann/