# overwhelmed by IOC choices

Tags: .net, ioc-container

There are so many IOC choices, that I don't know where to begin. I've looked at Spring.NET, Unity, Ninject, Windsor, and StructureMap so far, and I have no idea what makes one better than the other. So, what is your favorite IOC, and what feature(s) makes you use it over any other?

Comment: This is a duplicate - you'll likely find what you're interestred in at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/411660/enterprise-library-unity-vs-other-ioc-containers. (Or the blog post derived from the accepted answer here - http://elegantcode.com/2009/01/07/ioc-libraries-compared/)

Comment: I disagree, it is a different question. I'm asking which container people are using, and what feature is the most important. The question you reference is about other containers compared to Unity

Comment: furthermore, that is just one guy's opinion. I'm trying to collect information about what people on SO are using and why they think it is the best

Comment: The title is misleading - it started out as a question about Unity but evolved into a general summary of the differences between DI frameworks. However, you're right that it doesn't really offer opinions and testimonies, so I stand corrected. Nonetheless, I think you might find a lot of useful information in them given your question.

Comment: @Jeff, I agree that its useful, and I'm reading it now, thanks for the link

Answer (score 4):

Try to use [Common Service Locator](http://www.codeplex.com/CommonServiceLocator) and later you will be able to switch between containers. I prefer Unity (cos of holy faith in MS =) )  and Windsor cos of it power. Ninject has a very funny documentation, if you are not going to use it you should at least read its docs and visit its [site](http://ninject.org/) =)

Comment: it does have the best site by far

Comment: -1 avoid Common Service Locator. Don't use your IoC/DI container as a service locator.

Comment: Clarify your comment, why I should avoid using Common Service Loacator?

Answer (score 2):

I think more or less they have the same functionality. So it makes sense to look at:

- Documenatation quality
- Presense of comprehensive quickstarts
- Is is used in other well known products
- Is there a community around it
- How mature is it

For example, Unity:

- It has good documentation
- Quickstarts are pretty good
- It is used in Composite Application Guidance and Web Client Software Factory
- It has community around it
- It is only 1.2 (and 2.0 is coming) but nonetheless it is a successor of object builder

Answer (score 1):

For new projects I use Ninject now.
I like it for its "clean", modern and simple API
and its fluent configuration.