# Tools for detecting circular dependencies in dependency injection in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dependency-injection

Recently I started using dependency injection. In simple cases I didn't have any problems but with increasing complexity I found it difficult to quickly find circular dependencies.

Here's the example of circular dependency with constructor injection:

```
public class Class1
{
  public Class1(Class2 test2)
  { ... }
}

public class Class2
{
  public Class2(Class1 test1)
  { ... }
}
```

I use Unity IoC container. Circular dependency causes endless recursion and `StackOverflowException` to be thrown in the constructor.

Obviously this kind of dependencies is a code smell because it breaks single responsibility principle, so they should be localized and refactored.

Are there any tools for Visual Studio to detect these dependencies automatically?

Comment: "I use Unity IoC container." Switch to a different container. All the other common DI libraries (i.e. Autofac, Castle Windsor, Ninject, Simple Injector and StructureMap) will throw an expressive error instead of causing the AppDomain to be unloaded.

Comment: @Steven That's surprising drawback of Unity. Thank you Steven.